# Ternary operator: Compiler does not emit return reference of local variable warning

Tags: c++, reference, compiler-warnings, ternary-operator

I have implemented a naive function in C++ which compares two objects and returns  a reference of the max object of them increased by 1. I expect that a temporal object is created and when a reference of this object is returned, a warning of the compiler will be appeared due to a dangling reference of the temporary object. But no warning is generated. I hardly understand why this happens.

Below is the code that I have written

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
class A
{
    public:
     A():v(0)
    {
         std::cout << "A::ctror" <<std::endl;
    }
    A (int const & x):v(v + x)
    {

        std::cout << "convertion::ctror(int)" << std::endl;

    }
    static  A  &   max(A  & x , A  & y)
    {
        return x.v > y.v ? (x+1) : (y +1  ) ;
    }
    A & operator +( A const a )
    {
        this->v+=a.v;
        return *this;
    }
    int v ;
};
int main()
{
 A a1;
 A a2;
 a1.v = 1;
 a2.v = 6;
 A const &  a3 =  A::max(a1,a2);
 std::cout << a3.v << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: There’s no dangling reference here

Comment: @Kerndog73  why there is no dangling reference ? The x +1 creates a new object A that is returned by reference?Is this right?

Comment: `operator+` returns a reference. `a3` is a reference to `a2`. There is no dangling reference

Comment: `x+1` does not create a new object. Your `operator+` behaves like `+=`; it increments its left operand and returns a reference to it.

Comment: Your `A (int const & x):v(v + x)` constructor is broken: It reads from `v`, which is an uninitialized variable.

Comment: It is clear . However If I change the implementation of  max function in this way   A a = A();
return x.a < y.a ? (const_cast<A&>(x) +1) : a  ; still no warning is generated by the compiler

Comment: Why would the compiler generate a warning for legitimate code?

Comment: a is local variable that is return as reference. If I am not wrong compiler should generate warning

Comment: `a` is a local variable (a parameter local variable) that is not returned as a reference.  `a` is not returned at all.  `*this` is returned.

Comment: @getsoubl I get `.code.tio.cpp:19:18: error: ‘class A’ has no member named ‘a’`.

Comment: @melpomene you are right The correct is                                                                        
               A a = A();
  return x.v < y.v ? (const_cast<A&>(x) +1) : a  ;

Comment: @getsoubl Why `A a = A();` instead of just `A a;`? Why make a redundant copy? Also, why `const_cast`?

Comment: @melpomene, you are right , it is redundancy . const_cast is not needed as well

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As for the actual code in your question: No temporary objects are created because both your `max` and `operator+` take their arguments and return their results by reference. Thus the code is actually valid (if weird / misleading).

However, if we simplify your code to a version that actually contains a bug:

```
struct A
{
    static int &foo(int &x)
    {
        int a = 42;
        return x < a ? x : a;
    }
};

int main()
{
    int n = 0;
    return A::foo(n);
}
```

... we still don't get a warning, at least not with g++ 8.3.1.

This seems to be related to `foo` being a member function and/or marked `static`. Without the class wrapper:

```
static int &foo(int &x)
{
    int a = 42;
    return x < a ? x : a;
}

int main()
{
    int n = 0;
    return foo(n);
}
```

... there is still no warning.

Similarly, without `static`:

```
struct A
{
    int &foo(int &x)
    {
        int a = 42;
        return x < a ? x : a;
    }
};

int main()
{
    A wtf;
    int n = 0;
    return wtf.foo(n);
}
```

... no warning either.

But without the class and `static`:

```
int &foo(int &x)
{
    int a = 42;
    return x < a ? x : a;
}

int main()
{
    int n = 0;
    return foo(n);
}
```

```
.code.tio.cpp: In function ‘int& foo(int&)’:
.code.tio.cpp:4:24: warning: function may return address of local variable [-Wreturn-local-addr]
     return x < a ? x : a;
                        ^
```

... as expected.

I suspect this is a bug/oversight in g++.

Compilers aren't actually required to warn for bad code, but it seems unfortunate that a fairly obvious instance of broken code is not diagnosed.